Rudin RCA: Prelimary for his proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem
Rudin's statement of the theorem begins:
Let X
be a locally Hausdorff space, and let Λ
be a positive linear functional on Cc(X)
. Then there exists a σ
-algebra M
in X
which contains all Borel sets in X
and there exists a unique positive measure μ
on M
which represents Λ
in the sense that
(a)Λf=∫Xfdμ
for every f∈Cc(X)
(b)μ(K)<∞
(c) For every E∈M
, we have
μ(E)=inf{μ(V):E⊂V,Vopen}
(d) The relation
μ(E)=sup{μ(K):K⊂E,Kcompact} holds for every open set E and for every E∈M with μ(E)<∞
...
On p. 41, he states: "If μ satisfies (c) and (d), it is clear that μ is determined on M by its values on compact sets."
My question: Why does he need (c) here?  Isn't (d) enough for the conclusion that the compact sets determine the values?

Please use MathJax to format math, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

If you know $\mu$ on the compact sets, you get it on the open sets by (d), and then on every element of $M$ by (c).
